# Prove that $\sin 2\alpha=2 \sin \alpha \cos\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

In this triangle

[image]

$AD=AC=1$, $BC=a$, $BAC=2\alpha$

I thought $\sin 2\alpha=a$, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 7):

drop a perpendicular from $A$ to $DC$ and call the foot of the perpendicular $E.$ then $$DE =  EC = \cos \alpha, DC = 2 \cos \alpha.$$   now look at the right triangle $CBD$ with hypotenuse $2\cos \alpha$ and the $\angle BDC = \alpha,$  therefore the opposite side $BC$ is $$ BC = 2\cos \alpha \sin \alpha.$$  you can also look at the right angle triangle $ABC$ with hypotenuse $AC = 1, \angle BAC = 2\alpha$ which give the opposite side $$BC = \sin 2\alpha $$

therefore $$ BC = \sin 2\alpha = 2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha $$

Comment: Do we take CDB as alpha angle? If so, why?

Comment: @era,  yes, we do take $\angle ADC = \angle ACD = \alpha.$ and then find that $\angle BAC = 2\alpha$

Comment: This is a nice proof.  However, there are two typographical errors.  You meant right triangle $\color{red}{C}BD$ rather than $DBD$ and right triangle $ABC$ with hypotenuse $\color{red}{A}C = 1$ rather than $BC = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thank you very much for the close reading of my answer.

Comment: I had not seen this argument before, so it was certainly worth reading carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Try using an identity. $\sin 2\alpha = \sin \alpha + \alpha = \sin \alpha \cos \alpha + \sin\alpha\cos\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha $

Comment: The identity is right, but I guess that what it is looked for, is a geometrical proof

Answer (score 3):

$e^{2\alpha i}=\cos{2\alpha}+i\sin{2\alpha}=(e^{\alpha i})^2=(\cos{\alpha}+i \sin{\alpha})^2=\cos^2{\alpha}-\sin^2{\alpha}+2i \sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}$ Now equating the imaginary part gives the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a right triangle $ABC$ where the angle $A$ is right and the angle $B$ is $\alpha$. Let $M$ be the middle point of $BC$.

Then, the angle $AMC$ is $2\alpha$. Now apply on the triangle $AMC$ the law of sines:

$$\frac{\sin2\alpha}{AC}=\frac{\sin(90-\alpha)}{\frac12BC}$$

Since $AC=BC\sin\alpha$ and $\sin(90-\alpha)=\cos\alpha$ the identity follows.

*Remark:* This proof is only valid for acute angles.